# How to send email form google sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script

I want to create a script in apps script , which will send me an email once a day if today's date is in which cell.I want there to be a line header in the email.
Where is a code that tried.

```
function sendEmailOnDate() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  range = ss.getRange("task!C3:G8");
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  var cell = sheet.getRange("A1");
  if (cell.getValue() == new Date()) {
    MailApp.sendEmail("mymail@gmail.com", "Nowa wiadomość", "The date in cell A1 is today");
  }
}
```

Spreeadsheet name = task
I'm. also tired to put the current date in first cell A1.But It didn't work.
I got an error = Range not found

Comment: Welcome! You should probably remove your line 3 ```range = ss.getRange("task!C3:G8");```, first because you don't declare your range, correction : ```var range = ...```, and second because you don't use it (at least in your snippet)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function sendEmailOnDate() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  const dt = new Date(sheet.getRange("A1").getValue());
  const dtv = new Date(dt.getFullYear(),dt.getMonth(),dt.getDate()).valueOf()
  if (dtv == new Date(new Date().getFullYear(),new Date().getMonth(),new Date().getDate()).valueOf()) {
    MailApp.sendEmail("mymail@gmail.com", "Nowa wiadomość", "The date in cell A1 is today");
  }
}
```